# NullPointerException, error in thread trying to read spritesheet

Tags: java

I've been having trouble trying to get the complete file path for this program. This is just one file of many, but the only one that accesses files on the computer. It's weird because the program works fine on some computers, but not on others. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Assets {

private static final int width = 32, height = 32;

public static Font font28;

public static BufferedImage dirt, grass, stone, tree, rock;
public static BufferedImage wood;
public static BufferedImage[] player_down, player_up, player_left, player_right;
public static BufferedImage[] zombie_down, zombie_up, zombie_left, zombie_right;
public static BufferedImage[] btn_start;
public static BufferedImage inventoryScreen;

public static void init(){
    font28 = FontLoader.loadFont(“/Users/student/Desktop/TileGame/res/fonts/slkscr.ttf", 28);

    SpriteSheet sheet = new SpriteSheet(ImageLoader.loadImage(“/Users/student/Desktop/TileGame/res/textures/sheet.png"));

    inventoryScreen = ImageLoader.loadImage(“/Users/student/Desktop/TileGame/res/textures/inventoryScreen.png");

    wood = sheet.crop(width, height, width, height); //ERROR HERE

    btn_start = new BufferedImage[2];
    btn_start[0] = sheet.crop(width * 6, height * 4, width * 2, height);
    btn_start[1] = sheet.crop(width * 6, height * 5, width * 2, height);

    player_down = new BufferedImage[2];
    player_up = new BufferedImage[2];
    player_left = new BufferedImage[2];
    player_right = new BufferedImage[2];

    player_down[0] = sheet.crop(width * 4, 0, width, height);
    player_down[1] = sheet.crop(width * 5, 0, width, height);
    player_up[0] = sheet.crop(width * 6, 0, width, height);
    player_up[1] = sheet.crop(width * 7, 0, width, height);
    player_right[0] = sheet.crop(width * 4, height, width, height);
    player_right[1] = sheet.crop(width * 5, height, width, height);
    player_left[0] = sheet.crop(width * 6, height, width, height);
    player_left[1] = sheet.crop(width * 7, height, width, height);

    zombie_down = new BufferedImage[2];
    zombie_up = new BufferedImage[2];
    zombie_left = new BufferedImage[2];
    zombie_right = new BufferedImage[2];

    zombie_down[0] = sheet.crop(width * 4, height * 2, width, height);
    zombie_down[1] = sheet.crop(width * 5, height * 2, width, height);
    zombie_up[0] = sheet.crop(width * 6, height * 2, width, height);
    zombie_up[1] = sheet.crop(width * 7, height * 2, width, height);
    zombie_right[0] = sheet.crop(width * 4, height * 3, width, height);
    zombie_right[1] = sheet.crop(width * 5, height * 3, width, height);
    zombie_left[0] = sheet.crop(width * 6, height * 3, width, height);
    zombie_left[1] = sheet.crop(width * 7, height * 3, width, height);

    dirt = sheet.crop(width, 0, width, height);
    grass = sheet.crop(width * 2, 0, width, height);
    stone = sheet.crop(width * 3, 0, width, height);
    tree = sheet.crop(0, 0, width, height * 2);
    rock = sheet.crop(0, height * 2, width, height);
}

}
```

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: wood = sheet.crop(width, height, width, height);

Comment: the best way to perform operation on objects is to ensure the object is not null. coming to the issue, the path you given might be same on some machine and not on others

Comment: student is the username. but not all the machines has the same username. so this is not the right approach.

Comment: The object font28 must also be null in this case

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace as well.

Comment: @DerickDaniel from the moment you do `Something something = new Something(...)` despite the arguments, then `something` **is not `null`**. Thus we need the stacktrace for further info.

Comment: I'm going to assume ImageLoader.loadImage has a try catch, and catches FileNotFoundException? Just to rule out that the file 'sheet' can actually be found..